# Returning data from an array in "natural order"

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I've created a database which stores different attributes for a given user. I have implemented an algorithm which takes the username attribute and stores the contents of this attribute and stores it in an array. However for some reason, when printing the array it shows the users in alphabetical order. I want it to return the original order of my database. For context I am using the JDBC API in Java which takes MySQL syntax.

I have not implemented an `ORDER BY` statement, it is just a simple `SELECT FROM WHERE` statement but it seems to return alphabetically.

```
public void DisplayUsers() throws SQLException {

   String queryCount = "SELECT COUNT(Username) FROM UserInfo";
   String query = "SELECT Username FROM UserInfo";  
   declaringDataBase();

   rsObj = statObj.executeQuery(queryCount);
   String x = null;

    while(rsObj.next()){
      x = rsObj.getString(1); 
     }

   int rowNum = Integer.parseInt(x);

   rsObj = statObj.executeQuery(query);

   String UserArray[] = new String[rowNum];
   int counter = 0;

   while(rsObj.next()){

       String user = rsObj.getString("Username");
       UserArray[counter] = user;
       System.out.println(UserArray[counter]);
       counter++;
   }

}
```

The line `declaringDatabase();` simply calls another method to connect my database to the code. The count statement is taking the number of users under attribute Username and creating an integer to store as the length of the array. But anyway my `UserArray[]` returns values in alphabetical order, does anybody know why?

Comment: I have a feeling you meant to write the query `SELECT Username, COUNT(Username) FROMUserInfo GROUP Username ORDER BY Username ASC` instead.off those two queries.

Comment: Okay I just forgot a capital letter, I hadn’t cleared up the syntax yet. It’s not a big deal. Please focus on the question, do you have a solution: there is an order where each row has a number, I want it to return the values where the row number is in ascending order. If you don’t have a solution or constructive critismsm, please save yourself from the comment.

Comment: I did use an array?

Comment: Oh, I wanted to implement sorting algorithms and my teacher told me to use an array - I’m more familiar with them

Comment: @FranklinMemet What means *there is an order where each row has a number* ? Can you show the ddl and some sample data?

Comment: BTW https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/6053

Answer (score 3):

> I want it to return the original order of my database.

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  (Actually, in mathematics sets are always unordered.)  SQL result sets are unordered *unless you explicitly include an `order by` clause for the outermost `select`.

So, you need to include an ordering.

Most well-designed databases have an auto-incremented id for each row.  If yours has this, then it is easy to get the result set in insertion order:

```
SELECT Username
FROM UserInfo
ORDER BY UserId;  -- assuming `UserId` is an auto-incremented column
```

If you want alphabetical ordering, then you would use:

```
ORDER BY Username
```

If you want better performance, then you would define an index on the keys use for the `order by`.

Comment: I don't have an user_id column? any other suggestions?

Comment: @FranklinMemet . . . If you want alphabetical ordering, you want `order by UserName` anyway.

Comment: @GordonLinoff OP does not want alphabetical order: *I want it to return the original order of my database*

Comment: @Jens . . . It is a little hard to say, because of the title of the question.

Comment: @Jens There is no such thing as an original order though, though with an index-organized table you may have a somewhat deterministic order depending on the access path used by the query optimizer.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I know it. See my comment at the question.